# Using XSLT to add a Template to an existing XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to use XSLT (1.0) to transform an existing XSLT transformation. I need to add a param with a name passed by another param (done), add the Node contents (of a template) of a 2nd Param at the end of the existing XSLT, and add the param value into the Identity template of the output XSLT. For this question, I'm focusing on the **addition of a template node**. The Original XSLT looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="RemoveHistoryPastIllness" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="RemoveHistoryPastIllness" select="$RemoveHistoryPastIllness" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="/hl7:ClinicalDocument/hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody/hl7:component/hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root = '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.20']">
        <xsl:param name="RemoveHistoryPastIllness" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Need to remove the Illness History -->
            <xsl:when test="$RemoveHistoryPastIllness = 1"> </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I currently have this as my Transform, which presently does a direct copy of the existing XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl">  

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="myTemplate" >
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
            &lt;xsl:template
        match=&quot;/hl7:ClinicalDocument/hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody/hl7:component/hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root = &apos;2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.10&apos;]&quot;&gt;
        &lt;xsl:param name=&quot;RemoveTreatmentPlan&quot; /&gt;
        &lt;xsl:choose&gt;
            &lt;xsl:when test=&quot;$RemoveTreatmentPlan = 1&quot;&gt; &lt;/xsl:when&gt;
            &lt;xsl:otherwise&gt;
                &lt;xsl:copy&gt;
                    &lt;xsl:apply-templates select=&quot;@* | node()&quot; /&gt;
                &lt;/xsl:copy&gt;
            &lt;/xsl:otherwise&gt;
        &lt;/xsl:choose&gt;
    &lt;/xsl:template&gt;
            </xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>

    

    <!--Identity Match-->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm looking to get this for an output, with the contents of the `myTemplate` param as an actual template in the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" exclude-result-prefixes="xs hl7"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="RemoveHistoryPastIllness" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="ident">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="RemoveHistoryPastIllness" select="$RemoveHistoryPastIllness" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="/hl7:ClinicalDocument/hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody/hl7:component/hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root = '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.20']">
        <xsl:param name="RemoveHistoryPastIllness" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Need to remove the Illness History -->
            <xsl:when test="$RemoveHistoryPastIllness = 1"> </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="/hl7:ClinicalDocument/hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody/hl7:component/hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root = '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.10']">
        <xsl:param name="RemoveTreatmentPlan" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Need to remove the Treatment Plan -->
            <xsl:when test="$RemoveTreatmentPlan = 1"> </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Is this even possible? I've tried adding a node above and below the existing `apply-templates` within the `xsl:copy` in the Identity Template , and that's resulted in the node appearing outside the `xsl:stylesheet` tags on the output. Adding a node anywhere else results in errors.

I was asked for the purpose of this:
I'm going to be receiving a param name, and a template from user input.The new param and template need to be added to an existing XSLT document. My thought was to build a transformation, so without the user ever having to have access or the ability to update the transformation, the new param and template can be added to the existing document transform.  I hate the term Low Code, but ultimately thats what this is. Basically keeping the user out of the full (large) XSLT, that they probably won't have access to. This is part of a large ETL process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `myTemplate` parameter will be supplied in the form of an escaped string representing the XML of the template that needs to be added, you should* be able to produce the expected result using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="myTemplate"/>

<xsl:template match="/xsl:stylesheet">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$myTemplate" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--
(*) I say "should" because  an XSLT processor is not required to follow the instruction to disable output escaping (and will do so only if it is the one doing the serializing of the output). In general, using DOE is bad practice and should be used only when there is no other alternative.

If we knew what is the *real* purpose of this exercise, we could very likely suggest a better approach. At this point, any such attempt is no more than a wild guess.

Comment: You're right, I didn't give the real purpose. I'll also add this to the original q.  I'm going to be receiving a param name, and a template from user input. My thought was to build a transformation, without the user ever having to have access or the ability to update the transformation. Ultimately the resulting transform is going to be transforming a document based on the values of the param.  I hate the term Low Code, but ultimately thats what this is. Basically keeping the user out of the full (large) XSLT. 
User input: Param Name & Template ->this + DocTransformXSLT = NewDocTransformXSLT.

Comment: Additionally, this is the closest I've been able to get to what I need. I had to do some additional tweaking to get the parameter added, but this seems to work. I'll need to do more testing to make sure the resulting fix works as intended, but this is as close to a solution as I've been able to get.

Comment: I am afraid I still don't see the entire picture here. Hopefully my suggestion can work for you, but you should keep in mind that if the users are allowed to add a template of their own, they could override the entire stylesheet.

Comment: Understood. There will be additional processing to make sure the template is "good". It's also a solution for developers to use, with the understood risk, and auditing to revert improper changes. It's definitely a bit of a spaghetti situation, but thanks for the help, and I'll mark this as a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have are passing an additional template as a textual parameter to a stylesheet which uses it modify a second stylesheet, producing a third stylesheet, and then you execute that third stylesheet. I have used, and seen other people use, stylesheets that make changes to other stylesheets (sometimes called "meta-stylesheets"), but the technique is usually reserved for more complicated requirements, and I think it's likely you can achieve what you need more easily with the more common technique of using `xsl:include`.

My suggestion would be to create a stylesheet which includes your additional template, and also includes an `xsl:import` statement to import your original stylesheet. The new stylesheet is effectively a copy of the original, with the additional template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" >
    <xsl:import href="original-stylesheet.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template
        match="/hl7:ClinicalDocument/hl7:component/hl7:structuredBody/hl7:component/hl7:section[hl7:templateId/@root = '2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.22.2.10']">
        <xsl:param name="RemoveTreatmentPlan" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Need to remove the Treatment Plan -->
            <xsl:when test="$RemoveTreatmentPlan = 1"> </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```